# file programming in python

Tags: python

```
read_file = open ('C:\Users\Mahya\Desktop\\automate\Autosupports\\at1.txt','r')
content = read_file.readlines()
for line in content:
    if line.contains('===== BOOT TIME STATS ====='):
       print found
```

I want to read `'===== BOOT TIME STATS ====='` this line and print the lines that are below till next line 
please help

Comment: What do you mean by *print the lines that are below till next line*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to print the lines between the first and second occurrences of the given string:

```
read_file = open ('C:\Users\Mahya\Desktop\\automate\Autosupports\\at1.txt','r')
content = read_file.readlines()
found = False
for line in content:
    if line.contains('===== BOOT TIME STATS ====='):
        if found:
            break # Exit the for loop when finding the string for the second time
        found = True
    if found:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

Without testing:

```
read_file = open ('C:\Users\Mahya\Desktop\\automate\Autosupports\\at1.txt','r')
content = read_file.readlines()
i_found_the_block = False
for line in content:
    if "===== BOOT TIME STATS =====" in line:
       print ("found")
       i_found_the_block = True
    if i_found_the_block:
       print line
```

Comment: If you opened the file in a `with`-statement, and iterate over the file directly instead of using `readlines()`, this would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open ('C:\Users\Mahya\Desktop\\automate\Autosupports\\at1.txt','r')
for line in file:
    if '===== BOOT TIME STATS =====' in line: break
for line in file:
    if 'i wanna stop here' in line: break
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lineRange(lines, start, end):
    """Return all lines from the first line containing start
    up to (but not including) the first ensuing line containing end
    """
    lines = iter(lines)
    # find first occurrence of start
    for line in lines:
        if start in line:
            yield line
            break
    # continue until first occurrence of end
    for line in lines:
        if end in line:
            break
        else:
            yield line

def main():
    fname = 'C:/Users/Mahya/Desktop/automate/Autosupports/at1.txt'
    start = '===== BOOT TIME STATS ====='
    end = start # next section header?
    with open(fname) as inf:
        lr = lineRange(inf, start, end)
        try:
            lr.next()  # skip header
            print ''.join(lr)
        except StopIteration:
            print 'Start string not found'

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```